# Can't Update ADT plugin in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-adt

I have updated SDK and platform-tools of android through SDK manager for Eclispe, but when trying to update ADT-Plugins, it shows some error dialog with a message.

I also tried updating with downloaded ADT-plugin archive, still occurs same problem.

Any suggestions.

Error Dialog

[image]

Eclipse version

[image]

Comment: Did you try restarting your system?

Comment: Yes I did, but no use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found solution.

While updating ADT-Plugin with downloaded Archive, **un-check** "Contact all update sites during install to find require software" option in the "Install new Software" Wizard and say finish.

Say 'Yes' when it ask for restart eclipse.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I had this a few weeks ago as well. The only way that I could find to resolve the issue was to uninstall (delete the eclipse directory from where it is running from) and then re-install and install the plugins again from scratch.

Comment: Is there a way to revoke the changes?

Comment: Not that I kind anywhere, I tried searching for hours trying to resolve the problem but wasn't able to. That's why in the end I just gave up and deleted eclipse and started again. It doesn't take too long to do though so wasn't as bad as it sounds

Answer (score 0):

un-check "Contact all update sites during install to find require software" worked for me